# Dixit: what to do if two players cross the finish at the same time?

Tags: dixit

What do you do if two players cross the finish at the same time?

Does anyone have any rules on this? I can't see anything in the instructions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If two players cross the finish line at the same time, then the player with the most points wins. If they both have the most points the rules don't indicate any tiebreaker, but my suggestion is to just play another round, as it's a casual game and it will allow you to get in another round of fun.

Comment: This might cause problems if a third player overtakes the two 'winners' in de tie-breaker round.

Comment: @JarkoDubbeldam in that case, the third player wins.

Answer (score 5):

According to [these rules](https://ndsslibraryblog.files.wordpress.com/2015/12/dixit-rules-english.pdf),

> The game ends when one of the players has reached 30 points or when a player draws the last card. The player with the most points at the end of the game wins.

The player with the most points is the winner.

In the event of a tie, it's often the preferred resolution in a casual setting to declare that all the players tied for first are winners.

However, if you want a single winner, there's nothing appropriate to use as a tie-breaker, so just play more rounds until there's a clear winner.

Comment: I agree that having multiple winners is the most sensible judgement by the written rules, and should be the go-to for games that don't specify tie-breakers (as opposed to adjusting the game to force a single winner).

Answer (score -2):

### The game doesn't end when a player crosses the finish line (as uninuitive as it may seem)

From [the rules](http://en.libellud.com/index.php?option=com_zoo&task=callelement&format=raw&item_id=200&element=66b58ffc-c789-4cef-b9f1-2cb5226ebace&method=download&args%5B0%5D=47917eaf6bf739126f6d1509706527ce&Itemid=57) on the publisher's website (also available [in other languages](http://en.libellud.com/games/dixit#tabs-3)):

> **Game end**
>
> The game ends when the last card from the pack has been drawn. The player who’s the furthest on the scoring track is the winner.

Thus if you go past 30 points, you just take another lap.

There are no tiebreakers for if there is a tie when the last card has been drawn. Given the casual nature of the game, I'm going to guess that they are co-winners.

If having co-winners doesn't work for you, the only real option is to play additional rounds until someone comes out ahead.

Comment: [These rules](https://ndsslibraryblog.files.wordpress.com/2015/12/dixit-rules-english.pdf) say *the game ends when one of the players has reached 30 points or when a player draws the last card. The player with the most points at the end of the game wins.*

Comment: @ikegami Huh, the rules I've found were on the official website and have different text.

Comment: Sounds like i found a newer version. It makes no sense to keep going until there are no cards. There are thousands of cards out now.

Answer (score -3):

You follow the circle of turns in choosing which bunny moves first. Yoy dont move them all at once because that is not in the rules. Logic dictates that the person next to the person’s card being guessed will move first. If the moves to be taken are enough to reach 30, then that person wins, otherwise, the next person in turn will move and have the same opportunity to reach 30. There is obviously a reason why the game ends at 30, and counting which person has more points more than is definitely not what the intention of the rule is. Otherwise, this  would have been easily pointed out in the rules.

Comment: This is not said nor implied by the rulebook. It simply states “each player moves their game piece on the scoreboard as many spaces as points earned.” No reason to think there is any order for this at all. Also, “when a player reaches 30 points” is not the same as “when a player moves their marker to the 30 point space.”  You have points immediately the moment you earn them; it then takes time in real world games to actually move your marker. Moving your marker doesn’t give you any points, you get the points as soon as votes are revealed and scored.

Comment: Finally, the rules state “the player with the most points at the end wins”; and this would be strange wording if it were not possible for more than one player to reach 30.